# Three.js very slow with server sent event

Tags: three.js, web-worker, server-sent-events

i develop a game with Three.js which loads obj models from server depending on a stream from server sent event, all models are very simple and very low poly, the code runs well but with about 50 models loaded the event source makes it very very slow, i make the event source code inside a web worker which increased the performance but still not acceptable at all.
what should i do to enhance the performance?

Comment: .obj files are quite big. your best bet is to probably convert then to binary with the included python converter.

Comment: Is the slowdown specific to SSE? I.e. have you tried using AJAX requests to fetch the models, and it does not slow down after 50 models in the same way? If so, something is wrong, and you should post some of your client code and server code.
But if AJAX polling is equally slow then I agree with other comments that this is just due to heavy data.

Comment: the problem was in my client code, i was cloning the duplicated objects by object3d.clone() function to prevent reloading again when i removed this method and made it loads all objects as new it became normal also i noticed from console network the duplicated objects are loaded from cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to take a look at JSON 3D exporter project. It basically converts 3D objects into plain JSON files, it becomes really lightweight and so usefull in order to improve the time response. In order to do so, you will need Blender.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender